# Decrypting Error in Openssl using PHP

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-openssl

I send an encrypted base64 encoded JSON object

```
N4m4EBDjdCfq5V1JqjMXdO6PEjNEh1fAMaHPn....
```

to an API which reads and returns a response , I am facing trouble trying to decrypt the response. The response I get from the API is

```
� �Gֲ:й�@���BJ)3ࣗ�%���wW��u~��J�1��(�/�ik�A���Ԥ& ��g��yi�ُ�3��qxQ������4iM���k�o��k����k\�6�x9
```

My code for Decryption

```
$private_key = file_get_contents('privateKey.key');

    $res = openssl_pkey_get_private($private_key);

    $a_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);

    // Decrypt the data in the small chunks
    $chunkSize = ceil($a_key['bits'] / 8);
    $output = '';

    while ($response)
    {
        $chunk = substr($response, 0, $chunkSize);
        $response = substr($response, $chunkSize);
        $decrypted = '';
        if (!openssl_private_decrypt($chunk, $decrypted, $res, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING))
        {
            while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
         echo $msg . "<br />\n";
        }
        $output .= $decrypted;
    }

    openssl_free_key($res);

    echo '<br /><br /> Unencrypted Data: ' .$output;
```

The output after decryption is

```
�E�X,�/�၏�����2#>�o�����    1f�=�*�O���г���18}Yi�,�_�ڪ�|
```

but I am expecting a readable plain text response.

EDIT : I now understand that the encryption is happening at one end in Java, the sample code for encryption is

```
The code for using .pem file below: 
public static String encrypt(String rawText, PublicKey publicKey) throws 
 IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(rawText.getBytes("UTF-
8")));
}

public static RSAPublicKey getPublicKey(String filename) throws IOException, 
GeneralSecurityException {
    String publicKeyPEM = getKey(filename);
    return getPublicKeyFromString(publicKeyPEM);
}

public static RSAPublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws 
IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    String publicKeyPEM = key;
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "");
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    byte[] encoded = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyPEM);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new 
X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded));
    return pubKey;
}


private static String getKey(String filename) throws IOException {
    // Read key from file
    String strKeyPEM = "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        strKeyPEM += line + "\n";
    }
    br.close();
    return strKeyPEM;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
RSA necryptionService = new RSA();
try
   {
String file = "D:/public.pem";
                String data = "Hello Test"
       PublicKey publicKey = necryptionService.getPublicKey(file);
      String encryptedData = necryptionService.encrypt(data,publicKey);
       System.out.println(encryptedData); 
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

Where the string gets converted in the 3rd method, try this additional piece 
of code


    CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
    Certificate cer = fact.generateCertificate(is);

    logger.info("Public Key:::::::::::loaded"+cer.getPublicKey());
```

I send my request to the API using cURL and get back the java encrypted response.

The encrypted request is

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

The Private Key is

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Are you sure it is encrypted with the same algorithm on both sides? It seems like you are trying to use RSA as a stream cipher. If you have control over both endpoints you should look into using AES instead. Maybe with using RSA to only encrypt a one-time key for each request.

Comment: @rypskar : I do not have control over both endpoints. I only have control over the decryption. I need to look into AES.

Comment: You could check the specs for the endpoint again to find which algorithm it is encoded with. It also seems like the data you get back are not base64 encoded, or maybe it is zipped after it is base64 encoded?

Comment: I am not sure if the institution that built the API will tell me what encryption method they are using , but I will ask anyway . Also I believe the response is zipped after encoding if I am to go by the docs.

Comment: You should probably encode the encrypted message and provide the key. Folks who want to run the code cannot do anything with the non-printable characters. You should also state what the expected recovered test is.

Comment: did you base64 decode the respond before feeding it into the decryption loop ? why are decrypting in chunks and not passing the full respond to the function?

Comment: Yes I have tried that , that way the decryption throws up a NULL result. And If I pass the full response to the function then I get an error saying that the data is greater than mod len.